# How can we associate a page layout to a wiki page in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

From the web browser, in SharePoint 2013, is there a way I can associate a page layout (that has article page as it's content type), to a wiki page?  If so how do we go about that?  If this is a wrong approach, what would be a better way to associate a page layout to a wiki page?...FYI - I am working with a sub site that is using a team site template.

My Goal:
I would like to include snippets on my page layout, which will then associate to a wiki page.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, page layouts only work with publishing pages (the pages library). I don't know if this has changed in 2013.

Since you tagged this with SharePoint Enterprise, simply enable the publishing infrastructure and utilize pages.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  I understand now that I will have to do more custom work to my master template if I want anything customized around wiki page layouts (not Enterprise Wiki).